# How to locate shared object file in ubuntu repositories?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, ros

Can I locate a shared object file within a remote repository inside my system's sources?

For example, on my computer I can search:

```
dpkg -S libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so
```

The query returns the name of the package containing the file, if the package is installed.

Is there a way for me to search the system's remote sources and identify which package contains `libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so` so that I can install it with `apt-get install` afterwards?

Comment: Thanks @karel ! I could not solve the problem described above from the answer, but I might misunderstand the linked answer.  For example, https://packages.ubuntu.com/ seems to describe only packages provided by Ubuntu, can that be? Also, I used `apt-file search 'libgazebo_ros_laser.so'` but this didn't return a find. Do you think the answer help me to search the packages provided by the repositories listed in `sources.list.d` ?

Comment: Are the repositories listed in sources.list.d PPAs?

Comment: Yes, I think so. (If I understand dealing with sources correctly.) On my computer `sources.list.d` contains a file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list` which holds the packages containing the file `libgazebo_ros_laser.so`

Comment: Unfortunately, apt knows the file lists of only currently-installed packages. Apt does not keep a database of every possible file provided by every possible package. Most folks in your situation (I've been there, too) use a Search Engine, a bit of `apt search`,  and a bit of detective work: A bit of Google-fu looking for `libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser` turns up the package name to try.